# Что можно сделать с процессом Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, процесс

Не могли бы вы поведать мне какие-нибудь интересные функции для работы с процессами или потоками процессов в Windows? Мне не нужны какие-либо сложные связки функций, с которыми вы сами запаритесь (типа инжекта в чужой процесс)...просто единичные функции.

Answer (score 2):

Пожалуй, лучше всего бегло просмотреть список функций из API: [Process and Thread Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms684847(v=vs.85).aspx). Тогда будет понятно, что можно делать, а что - нет.

Answer (score 1):

TerminateProcess :)